# invalidate a session in SugarCRM

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

My application talks to SugarCRM. I need to test how my application behaves when it tries to call a REST method when its session has expired. How can I do so without waiting for timeout ?

Hint : not giving the session or giving a wrong session number gives error 10 : invalid login. I'm looking for error 11 : Session expired.

Thanks for you any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using PHP sessions, you could just delete the session file on the server and that would clear it out.

Comment: I'm writing a zimlet, that's javascript code for the Zimbra Collaboration Suite. I'm not using any session on my side, there's a login REST API call that your app has to make in order to talk to SugarCRM afterwards. That method call returns a session ID, which your application has to provide to every successive call to SugarCRM REST methods. When you say delete php session files, are those on SugarCRM server or on my app's server (zimbra) ?

Comment: Those would be on the SugarCRM server side. See this link for more information http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php